# Subsonic.DataService Missing in Subsonic 3.0.0.4?

Tags: sql, subsonic

How do I execute QueryCommand Object in SubSonic 3.0.0.4 without DataService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question can't you do the following:

```
ProjectNameDB.DefaultDataProvider.Execute....
```

Where ProjectNameDB is the class generated from Context.tt

Or something like:

```
QueryCommand myCmd = new QueryCommand("SELECT foo from bar", ProjectNameDB.DefaultDataProvider);
ProjectNameDBdb = new ProjectNameDB();
var result = db.DataProvider.ExecuteDataSet(myCmd);
```